# How can I make my android app open file located in lan network?

Tags: android, networking, lan

How can I make my android app open file located in lan network  like what es file explorer do ? 
I want my application  to do this without es file explorer or any program similar to it .

and  I mean to open the file itself directly without downloading it to sd card.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SMB protocol. Have a look here: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.nl/2014/02/android-sambha-jsifs-file-sharing.html?m=1

Comment: thanks greenapps but I don't want to download the files but open any file directly like what es file explorer does .

Comment: If es fileexplorer shows you the content of a file then that content is downloaded before showing.